# SQLite Почему не устанавливается через yarn, что делать? с npm не хочу совмещать, боюсь что потом ошибки будут

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite

Всем привет! Немного надоело когда делаешь туториал, и в середине проекта возникает косяк с установкой чего-либо, в этот раз у меня не устанавливается Sqlite... команда состоит из двух комманд
yarn add sqlite && yarn add --dev types/sqlite
первая устанавливается а вот вторая нет.

```
C:\Users\Луна\Desktop\CODE\nextjs\nextjs-frontend-test-project>yarn add --dev types/sqlite
yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/types/sqlite.git
Directory: C:\Users\Луна\Desktop\CODE\nextjs\nextjs-frontend-test-project
Output:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Что делать? Сейчас вышла ошибка скорее всего изза этого..

Comment: yarn add --dev `@`types/sqlite

Comment: @nörbörnën вау, точно) но увы пишет ошибку даже там. yarn add v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types%2fsqlite: Not found".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\Луна\\Desktop\\CODE\\nextjs\\nextjs-frontend-test-project\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Comment: у вас ведь ясно написано, что такого пакета нет. заходите на офф сайт, ищете пакет. я нашел только @types/sqlite`3`

Comment: кстати, если node-sqlite 4той версии то типы там не нужны, на сколько я вижу

Comment: @nörbörnën кстати да, говорится вроде так, но я запаниковал наверное и свалил на то что не установил строку которую устанавливал автор. У меня скорее в коде косяк, пишет что значение Undefined где то. Буду искать, благодарю вас

Comment: и @azlov за помощь!